# Integer literal as parameters of function declaration in cpp

Tags: c++, function-declaration

I'm almost familiar with `c` and `c++` programming. Today I was searching about function declaration when I suddenly came across a strange syntax in `c++` language.
I wrote below code:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int foo('3');
int bar(3);
int main(){
    
}
```

I've never seen defining the literals as function parameters! So I expected to get compile error when I compile this program:

```
$ g++ file.cpp
```

But it compiled without any problem!
So I'm curious to know what's the **meaning** and **usage** of `int foo('3');` and `int bar(3);` lines?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It means `int foo = '3';` and `int bar = 3;` respectively.

But it's not exactly equivalent, e.g. with classes `=` doesn't permit `explicit` constructors.

Comment: I'll examined your suggestion and yes... you're right. Can you also bring a reference which explains `int foo(3);` will be translated as `int foo = 3`?

Comment: @milad https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/initialization